# Am I breaking any log rules?

Tags: logarithms

Suppose I have the inequality $(\frac{A}{B})^X < (\frac{C}{D})\cdot(\frac{E}{F})^Y$ and I want X by itself.

Can I do this $X\cdot \log(\frac{A}{B}) < \log(\frac{C}{D})\cdot(Y\cdot \log(\frac{E}{F}))$?
Am I breaking any rules on the right-hand side?

Comment: Log of a product is the sum of the logs. So you are missing a $+$ sign on the right.

Comment: Please learn how to use basic Latex before posting a question. Also yes, you are breaking the rules. You need a + sign.

Comment: Thanks, I will try to learn latex later on

Comment: $\log (ab)=\log a + \log b$

Answer (score 4):

It should be
$$X\log \left(\frac{A}{B}\right)=\log \left(\frac{C}{D}\right)+Y\log \left(\frac{E}{F}\right)$$
You did not break the log into addition as $\log xy =\log x +\log y$

Answer (score 0):

Yes!!! You need to apply the rule of addition for logarithmic functions.

Right hand side should be log(C / D) + (Y * log(E / F)).

Comment: Please use mathjax

Answer (score 0):

One of the logarithm rules is $\log (ab)=\log a + \log b$. Therefore, on the right, it should be $\log (\frac{C}{D}) + Y \log (\frac{E}{F})$.